# FOREIGN KEY Constraint Failed: SQlite3

Tags: database-design, sqlite, constraint

I have two tables, created as below,

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Artists(
   ...> ArtistId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> ArtistName TEXT NOT NULL
   ...> );
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Albums(
   ...> AlbumId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> AlbumName TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> Year TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> ArtistId INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...> FOREIGN KEY(ArtistId) REFERENCES Artists(ArtistId)
   ...> );
```

`.table` returns the following,

```
sqlite> .table
Albums   Artists
```

foreign key pragma is set to `ON`

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
```

However, When I try to insert data as below results in FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO Albums VALUES (NULL, 'Killers', '1981', 7);
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
sqlite>
```

I am a database learner. Could someone point out what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: That worked. Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to insert `Albums.ArtistId` value (`7`) which is absent in `Artisis.ArtistId` values list now. So insertion fails.

You cannot insert album of `<unknown>`, FK claims this is impossible, and server prevents this.

Insert artist with `ArtistId=7` first, then insert his albums.